# Работа с таблицами

Tags: html, jquery

Есть обычная html таблица, как я с помощью jquery могу определить на какой столбец наведен курсор?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$("td").hover(function(){ alert($(this).index()); });
```

Comment: добавил скобочку)

Comment: да, спасибо :)